# React service-worker is not detected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am trying to turn my webapp into a PWA, but it does not work.
I created a react app, made a build, now hosting it on apache server by adding the contents of the build folder into the htdocs folder. I'm also using a .htaccess file to fix ReactRouter problems.

My manifest.json contains this:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "prefer_related_applications": "false",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I changed "start_url": "." to "/" to see if it works, but it does not.

My serviceWorker.js file contains this:

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read ....

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
    window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
      // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
      window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
      // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
      window.location.hostname.match(
        /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
      )
  );
  
  export function register(config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
      const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
      if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
        // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
        // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
        // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
        return;
      }
  
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
  
        if (isLocalhost) {
          // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
          checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);
  
          // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
          // service worker/PWA documentation.
          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
            console.log(
              'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
                'worker. To learn more, visit ...
            );
          });
        } else {
          // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
          registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register(swUrl)
      .then(registration => {
        registration.onupdatefound = () => {
          const installingWorker = registration.installing;
          if (installingWorker == null) {
            return;
          }
          installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
            if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
              if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
                // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
                // content until all client tabs are closed.
                console.log(
                  'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                    'tabs for this page are closed. See....'
                );
  
                // Execute callback
                if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                  config.onUpdate(registration);
                }
              } else {
                // At this point, everything has been precached.
                // It's the perfect time to display a
                // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
  
                // Execute callback
                if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                  config.onSuccess(registration);
                }
              }
            }
          };
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
      });
  }
  
  function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
    // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
    fetch(swUrl, {
      headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
    })
      .then(response => {
        // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (
          response.status === 404 ||
          (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
        ) {
          // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
            registration.unregister().then(() => {
              window.location.reload();
            });
          });
        } else {
          // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
          registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log(
          'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
        );
      });
  }
  
  export function unregister() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(registration => {
          registration.unregister();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error.message);
        });
    }
  }
```

My index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: ....
reportWebVitals();

serviceWorker.register();
```

I added the serviceWorker.js file to src, public, and the root directory, then used "npm run build". I added it everywhere just to try to fix it.

I'm getting this error in the console when I start localhost:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) serviceworker.js:1

After running lighthouse and click on PWA, I get this:

> Failure reason No matching service worker detected. You may need to
> reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the
> current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest.

The URL is "localhost".

How can I fix it?

Comment: In your question have three diffrent file names for the service worker: serviceworker.js, serviceWorker.js and service-worker.js => check the spelling.
Check if you can access the serviceworker.js file in your browser url => https://localhost/myapp/serviceworker.js

Comment: It looks like React creates a `serviceWorkerRegistration.js` (perhaps previously called `serviceWorker.js` and a `service-worker.js`. I've got the same thing (but also this problem, so...)

Answer (score -2):

Change

`import * as serviceWorker from 'serviceworker'`

to

`import * as serviceWorker from 'serviceworker.js'`

and make sure `serviceworker.js` is at the root of your project folder.

Comment: If I try this, I get a compilation error (`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './serviceWorkerRegistration.js' in `...)